# If statement does not accept proper value

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

When I debug this code I noticed that the If statement does not ever switch the boolean type sales variable to true... This is bugging me because I know that answer = "y" when it gets to the If statement. Help please! and yes I did import java.util.Scanner

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean sales = false;
String answer;

System.out.print("Will you be calculating the Sales department pay aswell? (y or n):");
answer = input.nextLine().trim();

if (answer == "y")
{
    sales = true;
}
```

i have

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to compare strings is:

```
if (answer.equals("y"))
```

Notice that in Java `equals()` is used for testing *equality* between objects, whereas the `==` operator is used for testing *identity*. They're two different concepts, and most of the time you're interested in equality.

As the @MadProgrammer suggests, inverting the comparison order is a good idea - it'll be safer in case `answer` is `null`:

```
if ("y".equals(answer))
```

Comment: Nit Pick- `"y".equals(answer)` or `"y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)` might be a better suggestion

Comment: @MadProgrammer fair enough, I updated my answer :)

Comment: You see, now I have to up-vote you :P

Answer (score 0):

You should use `equals()` to compare strings:

```
if (answer.equals("y")) {
```

Comment: Nit Pick- `"y".equals(answer)` or `"y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)` might be a better suggestion